# CSS not pulling in for jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery

I want to add a jQuery dialog modal to a form page. When the dialog box is triggered I see the the text content but with no CSS. I'm pulling in the jquery in the functions.php for the page:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
```

The jquery css (jquery-ui-dialog.css) is under my wp-includes/css directory.
I tried adding

```
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-dialog');
```

but it not work. Does anybody know the proper way to enable jQuery Dialog.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );`

Comment: Also make sure that you add the 'wp-dialog' class to the dialog itself, so it can take advantage of those styles. They're pretty ugly though. Might be better off using the jQuery UI themed styles anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `jquery-ui-dialog` style defined in WordPress Out of the box, you need to ue the stylesheets manually, when i needed to enqueue the jQuery-UI style i pulled it from google api CDN

```
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
```

but you can enqueue a local copy if you want like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'myStylesheet', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/path/stylesheet.css' );
```

Comment: But, as the OP pointed out, WP3.x ships with jquery-ui-dialog.css out of box in `wp-includes/css/`. Strange that the stylesheet wouldn't be registered by default. `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );` queues it up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the jquery-ui-dialog style in frontend using:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-jquery-ui-dialog' );
```